# Unity erased all my progress on my project back to original state

Tags: unity-game-engine

I started a new project and after closing and reopening it the next day, all progress was gone. It didn't crash and there weren't any abnormalities. I didn't touch any files in file explorer so it's not like I could've reverted the project or something. And yes I saved, I always save. Recycling bin is empty so it wasn't deleted. So I haven't much idea what the cause could've been, or what else to put really.

But is there any explanation for what could have caused this so next time in the future I can prepare for all my progress being erased out of the blue. And is there any way I can retrieve the files back somehow too?

Using version 2020.3.2f1

Comment: @bolov Git LFS is certainly one option for Unity 3D but I found that depending on what LFS client you use large files may or may not be automatically downloaded when cloning/switching branches which just confuses tools like Unity or say Photoshop thus adding another complicated step.

Comment: project 101, keep a backup, and probably version control. Unity is finicky, you try one experimental thing then everything gets busted all at once.

Comment: Forget tedious _Git LFS_ and buggy _Plastic SCM_ and go straight for _[Perforce - "...Helix Core is **free for up to 5 users & 20 workspaces** ..."](https://www.perforce.com/products/helix-core/free-version-control)_.  Or if you have **Azure**, grab _[**Enhanced Studio Pack** - "**free** tools for up to **5 users to deploy on Microsoft Azure**"](https://www.perforce.com/perforce-and-cloud)_

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking through temp files? Because I had this problem too a while ago and was able to retrieve the data which was hidden in the files somewhere. I had a backup and it didn't help because it didn't save to the backup obviously. I don't know why Unity still has this problem and there's not a lot of help on the internet regarding it either

Comment: Yeah good point, if it didn't save to the computer then it wouldn't have saved to a git. No one else is being helpful so I'll see if there's anything in the files with traces of my data. Thanks for being so helpful

Comment: "And is there any way I can retrieve the files back somehow too?" We addressed this question. Prevention is the best thing to do, keep a backup.

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to creating your project without being logged into Unity Hub, then re-opening it while being logged in to Unity Hub; this has been plaguing new prototype projects and has been quite extensively discussed here:

https://forum.unity.com/threads/all-assets-deleted-project-reset-when-launched-through-unityhub.1157303/

Multiple people reporting fresh projects suffering from this, with Unity nuking all the assets. If the project passes the first re-load then it'll persist, but this bug will sadly be destroying new fresh projects on the first re-load attempt and has been reproduced by multiple people on e.g. the above thread. Seems to be related to reloading the project using the flag `-cloneFromTemplate`.